# The most efficient and parsimonious method to rename observations in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, data-analysis

I have the following column in a larger tibble (for sake of showing on stackexchange I isolated it in its own tibble)

```
# A tibble: 36 x 1
   `sperm$BMI.Category`
   <fct>               
 1 Normal              
 2 Normal              
 3 Normal              
 4 Obese               
 5 Overweight          
 6 Overweight          
 7 Normal              
 8 Overweight          
 9 Overweight          
10 Overweight          
# ... with 26 more rows
```

I want to convert them to numeric values so I can use them for statistical work.
I was hoping that this would work to replace `Underweight` with `1`

```
sperm$BMI.Category[sperm$BMI.Category=="Underweight"] <- "1"
```

I assume  an `ifelse` or something to that effect is going to be the most efficient means to do this?
Could somebody please provide the most streamlined manner with minimal code?
Also how could one correct the current attempted method for it to be functional?

Comment: look into `dplyr`'s `case_when()`.. and loose the quotes around the number `"1"`, or else it will be handled as a string.

Comment: The simplest way is `sperm$BMI.Category <- factor(sperm$BMI.Category)`. Factors are coded internally as integers starting at 1, so you now have whole numbers. If you want to *see* them as ints, just do `as.integer(sperm$BMI.Category)`.

Comment: "I want to convert them to numeric values so I can use them for statistical work." There is an excellent chance that this is not necessary (or even advisable) at all.

Comment: Also, *I want to convert them to numeric values so I can use them for statistical work.* R's modeling functions will coerce to factor automatically. Try before doing something.

Comment: @Roland, could you explain your comment further please?

Comment: 1.) Many statistics functions in R will do it for you. 2.) Those that won't are likely the wrong approach for your data (like, e.g., using OLS regression when you should use ordinal regression).

Comment: Ok thank you for your comments. I was wanting to employ a logistic regression using all variables in the data set and was under the assumption that such a conversion is fairly commonplace?

Comment: Yes, it is so commonplace, that R is already doing it for you. Your vector is a factor; each level is encoded as integers 1-m, but given a label ("Normal","Overweight","Obese"). That is, your vector is containing categorical data. When you want to use a statistic analysis on data with a categorical variable (such as here), factors are the way to go. And you do not have to concern yourself about renaming the levels to 1-m.

Comment: @MrGumble so the fact that I created a factor and defined levels means its already in the correct format?

Comment: @AsifLalDin Yes, although it might vary depending on the individual package/method/model you are using.

Comment: @MrGumble, many thanks !